# EMD-SVR method for time series

Tags: time-series, svm, forecasting

Has anyone attempted to use Empirical Mode Decomposition(EMD)-Support Vector Regression(SVR) in nonstationary time series forecasting? It seems quite interesting. As I observed it has high performance compared with single SVR. But I didn't find it as a real approach for time series.

Comment: Have you considered effect of end-points on forecasting accuracy using EMD?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: yes, I studied on it and found 4 approaches (Mirror, Coughlin′s, Slope-based, Rato′s). But they also did not give high performance as on the papers that I read. Have u stuied any?